# Find the interval for which $2\arctan x + \arcsin \frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}$ is an independent of x?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I used formula and simplified the expression to $\Rightarrow 4\tan^{-1} x$

Comment: Take the derivative and see where it is $0$

Comment: @AnuragA yes that makes total sense as derivative would mean when the tangent is parallel to x axis henceforth function attaining the same values for all $x$ where $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Comment: But what about the interval ?

Comment: @Peter question setter might have meant the generalisation of required values of $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $\arctan x=y\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-\pi\le2y\le\pi$

$\arcsin\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}=\arcsin(\sin2y)$
$=\begin{cases} 2y &\mbox{if } -\dfrac\pi2\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2 
\\  \pi-2y & \mbox{if } 2y>\dfrac\pi2
\\ -\pi-2y & \mbox{if } 2y<-\dfrac\pi2 \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

We may replace $x$ with $\tan\theta$: in order to study the behaviour of $2\arctan x+\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$, we may just study the behaviour of
$$ g(\theta) = 2\theta + \arcsin(\sin(2\theta)) $$
over $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. $g(\theta)$ equals $4\theta$ over $\left[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$, $-\pi$ over $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{4}\right]$ and $\pi$ over $\left[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, hence the original function is constant over $[1,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,-1]$.

Here it is the graph of the original function over $[-2,2]$:

$\hspace2in$[image]

Comment: @SujithZis: it is suggested by the half-angle formula for the sine function: $\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$ is a generic point on the unit circle.

Comment: @SujithZis: yes, the map $x\to\arctan(x)$ is a smooth bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: So what does this independent of x mean , 4arctan x is dependent on x even in your interval .?

Comment: @SujithZis: The problem is yours, I believe you know what "independent" means in that context. My interpretation of the word is just "constant". g is constant over two intervals, hence your function is constant over two intervals, because the tangent/arctangent function gives a bijection.

Comment: And the given function *does not* equal 4 arctan(x) on the whole real line, as my answer clearly shows.

Comment: is there any way by which i can justify that dy/dx<0 , then i will be easily able to coincide with your answer

Comment: @SujithZis: the derivative of the original function is $$\frac{2\cdot\text{sign}(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}. $$ That is zero over $\mathbb{R}\setminus[-1,1]$.

Comment: Oh now i know where i went wrong $\arcsin \frac{2x}{1+x^{2}}=2\arctan x$ only for $x\in [\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}] $ right ?

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=4tan^{-1}(x)$ is invertible on $\mathbb R$.

The inverse function
is $g(x)=\tan(\frac{x}{4})$ with $x\in (-2\pi,2\pi)$.

Comment: Im not able to clearly understand ..... **where $4\tan^{-1} x$ is independent of x** are they asking the values of $x$ for which the the graph would become a straight horizontal line ?

Comment: "independent of x" confused me, too. Perhaps, I got the meaning wrong. In this case, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The region of independence is outside the unit circle, i.e. |x|>1.  Inside the unit circle the approximation you have used applies.

Comment: Umm could you please tell me in a diluted manner , which approximations are you referring to and I'm not able to picture up any circle

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say the approximation, the simplified expression you have used 4 \tan^{-1} (x) holds within the unit circle, i.e. when |x| <1, outside of the unit circle (this is assuming x is a complex quantity, if x is real then I mean when x>1 or x<-1) the function evaluates to zero.